# Sending attribute to edit form in spring mvc code

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I want to populate values to a form. Below is the code i have written.

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/editBankAccount/{accountName}")
public String editBankMethods(ModelMap modelMap,
        @PathVariable String accountName) {

    BankAccount bankAccount = managePaymentMethods.getBankAccount(
            sessionService.getUser(), accountName);

    return "editBankAccount";
}
```

Here is my field in JSP 
editform.jsp

```
<form:form>
<div class="form-group -oneX-col-sm-8">
                <label class="-oneX-textfield__floatingLabel" for="routingNumberInput">${text.global.routingNumber}</label>
                <form:input class="-oneX-textfield__input" path="routingNumber" type="text" id="routingNumberInput">
            </div>

</form:form>
```

I have tried changing the code in my controller from

```
return "editBankAccount";
```

to

`return new ModelAndView("editBankAccount", "command", bankAccount);` and changed the return type from String to ModelAndView.

Although my code compiles file, when I execute it I do not see the styling or labels in my JSP. All I see is my fields. Looks like its creating a new Modelandview.

What should be the line of code that I should write to not create a new ModelandView and simply pass my object to the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can use set and get Attribute.Set your attribute in Servlet class and get it in JSP page.

```
modelMap.setAttribute("Attribute",bankAccount);
```

where Attribute is variale-name and bankAccount is object.

in JSP page use scriplets,

```
<% BankAccount bankAccount=(BankAccount)modelMap.getAttribute("Attribute");%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get the attributes to my JSP page using the following code in the controller.

```
BankAccount bankAccount = managePaymentMethods.getBankAccount(
                sessionService.getUser(), accountName);
        modelMap.addAttribute("bankAccount", bankAccount);
        return "editBankAccount";
```